# Installing a program in Linux via package

Tags: package-management, fhs

I'm trying to create a `*.deb`-Package to install a program I have written. It consists of three executables which hash to be in the same subdirectory. Example:

```
.../myprogram/
    |
    +- Program A
    +- Program B
    +- Program C
```

I thought I can store them in `/usr/share/...` but lintian gives an error. So I read that in `/usr/share/...` arch-dependent objects can not have a place. But where else?
It is necessary that the executables are grouped in a "own" subfolder.

When I look into e.g. `/usr/bin/` there are no subfolders for programs.

Answer (score 3):

A Debian binary package should not contain files in `/opt`. Per the FHS, this is for locally installed packages only. This will be [flagged by lintian](http://lintian.debian.org/tags/dir-or-file-in-opt.html).
Doing this will earn you an automatic reject by Debian, assuming it gets past your sponsor. No package in the official archives has files in `/opt`. Placing user-level executables at the top level of `/usr/bin` is correct. Why do you want the executables in a sub-directory? In any case, creating a subdirectory in `/usr/bin` for your executables will not work, because the subdirectory will  not be in the path.

A alternative approach is to use a symbolic link in `/usr/bin` to a location somewhere else in the filesystem, typically `/usr/lib`, `/etc/alternatives`, or `/usr/share`. However, I think most of the time the right thing to do is to put those executables in `/usr/bin` directly.

Comment: Note that any links placed in `/etc/alternatives` should be managed by running `update-alternatives` in the post install script and not added directly.

Answer (score 0):

you have several possibilities:

- `/opt` stands for optional you can put them in a specific folder but it will not populate the PATH by default, then creating a symbolic link in `/usr/bin` could allow you to use them from `/opt`. **This seems to be not a valid option if you use `.deb` files**
- You can also put them in `/usr/bin` without bothering about anything, and do not put them in a specific folder

Comment: I have tested it but linian gives the error `E: datachecker: dir-or-file-in-opt opt/foo/`.

Comment: What is linian ?

Comment: `lintian` is a lint-program to check debian packages: http://lintian.debian.org/

Comment: @Christoph I can't help you with that, sorry